# Init array of object and pass values

Tags: java, object, init

I know there are plenty of question like this in the forum, but after searching for a good while I havent found the answer. I'm also very new to programming so dont flame me please.

I want to creat 8 objects off my class and pass different values to them.

f.e.

```
public class exampleClass(){
int value;
}
```

and then init them:

```
for(int i=0; i<7; i++){
exampleClass c= new  // I get lost at this point
                    //and how can we pass "i" to the var "value" inside the new objects?
}
```

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give `ExampleClass` a constructor to populate the value. For example:

```
public class ExampleClass {
    private final int counter;

    public ExampleClass(int counter) {
        this.counter = counter;
    }
}

...

ExampleClass[] array = new ExampleClass[7];
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = new ExampleClass(i);
}
```